# Multiple tapped events executing on a single tap

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have multiple spans within a label. Some spans have a tapped event, and some don't. If two spans with a tapped event wrap to the same line, tapping on the last span will trigger both of the tapped events. If the two spans don't wrap and are on separate lines, it works fine.

```
<Label VerticalOptions="Start" 
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontSize="Micro"
                Margin="70,0,70,0"
                LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="This text cannot be tapped. " ></Span>
                        <Span Text="This text can " TextDecorations="Underline">
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTextOneTapped"/>
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span>
                        <Span Text="and "></Span>
                        <Span Text="this text can also be tapped" TextDecorations="Underline">
                            <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTextTwoTapped"/>
                            </Span.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Span>
                        <Span Text="."></Span>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
```

```
private void OnTextOneTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Tap Alert", "You Tapped Text One", "OK");
        }
```

If the screen displays the tapped events text on different lines, it works fine:

This text cannot be tapped. This text can 
 and this text can also be tapped.

If any wrapping occurs where part of the tapped event shares a line with another tapped event, clicking on the latter of the two will cause both tapped events to fire:

This text cannot be tapped. This text 
 can and this text can also be tapped.

Tapping on the text "this text can also be tapped" will fire both OnTextOneTapped and OnTextTwoTapped. Tapping on the text "This text can" will only fire OnTextOneTapped.

Are my tapped event spans too close together (only separated by the word "and")? I only want one tapped event to fire per tap.

Comment: Have a test with FontSize="Large" and different background color for your spans.

Comment: I tried this and the issue still occurs. I don't think it's an issue with the spans overlapping since after setting them as different background colors, there were no overlapping parts.

Comment: On Xamarin github repo, [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10520) and [another one](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11657) may suit you, which still remain open.

Comment: The second link is exactly my issue. Thank you for linking that.

Comment: Alright, instead of splitting into multiple labels, I was thinking of providing extra links by the end of the long text, which goes like some [footnotes](https://www.ostraining.com/cdn/images/wordpress/footnotes/media_1446220460508.png).

Answer (score 0):

I have solution other for you:

- Solution: You make a stacklayout contains multiple label, and excute tapped event.

Comment: This seems like a workaround, not a solution. Maybe I'm not using spans correctly but it seems like the concept I'm going for is possible.